# Define a new type of memory

Tags: c++, gcc, memory

Is it possible to define a new type of memory.  For example in some embedded systems compilers you can do this:

```
__flash const char array[] = "This is memory in flash (not ram) so I can waste it!";
```

So is it possible to go even crazier and define a new type of memory (like say an SD card).

I am basically asking is it possible to define what an SD card is (how to access data in it) and then declare a variable in the sd memory. (every where it sees a write it calls the sd method, every where it sees a read it calls the sd method):

```
class SDCard{
public:
  void write(void* data,size_t length);
  void* read(size_t length);
  void* memAlloc(size_t length);

};

__sd char myVar;  //Grabs an address in the sd card based on SDCard::memAlloc
myVar = 'A';  //Calls whatever I defined the sd card write operation as
char other = myVar;  //Calls whatever I defined the sd card read operation as
```

I am using gcc if I can do something special with that (I am almost willing to modify the compiler source to allow me to do this).

Something like this is possible, but there are a few issues:

```
struct Vol_t{   //Would represent an SD card an external RAM or any other memory
    void write(void* data,size_t len,size_t add) const{}
    void* read(size_t len,size_t add) const{}
};
template<Vol_t* sd, class Type,size_t address>
struct MemDef{  //Wrap your type with this (maybe add -> operator support later
    void operator=(Type&& data){
        sd->write(&data,sizeof(data),address);
    }
    operator Type&(){
        return *reinterpret_cast<Type*>(sd->read(sizeof(Type),address));
    }
};

Vol_t SD;  //Initialize our SD card
MemDef<&SD,int,0xdeadbeaf> sdVar;  //Declare an int variable on the SD card

int main(int argc,char** args){
    sdVar = 12;   //Writes to the SD card
    int local = sdVar;  //Reads from the SD card
    system("Pause");
}
```

Problems with this approach:

- Optimizer must do every single read/write----it **cannot** do any optimizations on a variable declared in this way.  (this is the major issue)
- It is a little inelegant (but it does get the job done)
- You have to specify what memory address to use (It would be awesome if the compiler could somehow figure all of that out **before** compilation and automatically

So maybe I have to add a keyword to gcc (if that is the case please point me in the right direction to get started).

**Edit:** there is another problem with this approach.  If a type has a pointer to another variable that variable will not be initialized on the SD card (only the pointer will).

Comment: are you talking about a bare-metal application or an OS-backed scenario? __flash works on embedded because GCC puts "flashed" data in a special section (e.g. .progmem.data in AVR), GCC also knows that it has to read those data with the LPM instruction...

Comment: No, the available of that address space is target specific. In other words, it has to have have meaning for the specific processor you are compiling code for.

Comment: This is going to be an embedded systems.  I am basically asking is it possible to define what an SD card is (how to access data in it) and then declare a variable in the memory. (every where it sees a write it calls the sd method, every where it sees a read it calls the sd method).

Comment: @DarthRubik Flash doesn't work that way. You wind up having to cache the modified pages in RAM until you can complete an erase/update cycle. Otherwise your program would run as slow as molasses and you'd burn up the flash.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I know that is not how flash works....I am wondering if you can do the SD card thing though

Comment: You could easily make `SDCard` templated on the address and size of a data item, then read/write them yourself: `SDCard<addr,char> myVar; myVar.write('A'); char other = myVar.read();`

Comment: @DarthRubik SD cards are flash.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I was talking about __flash in embedded micros

Comment: @MarkRansom That seems promising but I want it to be able to do all of this at compile time (allocate where variables are going to be stored on the sd card at compile time)

Comment: @DarthRubik And, as I explained, it's not possible because flash doesn't work that way. Performance would be terrible and you'd blow through the flash's erase cycles. You have to cache flash in RAM (to coalesce writes and avoid blocking) when it's modified in "small bits". That defeats your objective of not using RAM.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't want fast read/writes....I just want to know if this is even possible. (but that is a good point about the huge read/write blocks with SD cards)

Comment: So maybe a better example is an external ROM attached to the micro controller (instead of an SD)

Comment: Most compilers already have an extension for this ; you can define arbitrary section names and then assign those sections to locations in the linker script

Comment: @M.M Really.....Hmm....Sounds very promising indeed

Comment: Why don't you just `mmap()` your SD-card?

Comment: @cmaster What is that?

Comment: It's a system function that maps the contents of any file, including device files, into your address space. After the `mmap()` call, you can access it as if you just had read the entire file into one huge buffer. Given the right arguments to `mmap()`, the kernel will also update the file itself with the data you write to that memory region. Note that it is perfectly ok for the mmaped file to exceed the size of the available memory: there is no need for all of the data to be present in memory at the same time; the kernel can take care of that (might slow things down due to swaps, though).

Comment: @cmaster This is a micro controller (it does not have a kernel)

Comment: Ah, ok, without a kernel `mmap()` is indeed out of question.

Comment: Loading code and data into system memory of whatever sort is the job of the system loader.  That loader will use an executable file format, and those formats tend to support the hardware they're meant to run on, but the details will be system- and format- and even compiler-specific.  Doing it at runtime is a separate issue; several OS's have ways of dynamically allocating storage with various attributes.

Comment: @DarthRubik: the code example you posted is VERY different from your original question!!! At first you wanted something like GCC's __flash, which "On the AVR target, [...] can be used [...] to put read-only data into the flash memory and access that data by means of the special instructions LPM or ELPM needed to read from flash". In your code example, instead, you are simply trying to implement a transparent interface to external memory. They are VERY different things.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned [placement new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) yet. By writing an overloaded `new` operator, an additional argument could be used to enforce a certain memory region. This only works for things that 'look' like memory, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There could be two cases:

1. The hardware is such that a certain range of addresses maps to the SD card, and data can be written/read from the SD card using normal memory access instructions, within that range. Regular pointers are used.
2. Special instructions/functions need to be used to read/write to the SD card. For example an `SDCard::read` function, which calls a special function on the OS (if any), or an interrupt instruction.

`__flash` is a GCC extension. It uses a different instruction to access the memory, and locates `static` data on another segment. But it cannot be generalized in this way using C++ alone. It also can't be used with dynamic allocation.

## First case (range of addresses)

To use regular pointers to read/write data to the SD card, they need to be marked `volatile`. This way the compiler does not optimize away and reads/writes. `volatile` means the memory may be changed/be used from outside the program, like for instance the hardware writing it to a SD card. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv .

For example

```
volatile char* data = 0x00010000;
memcpy(data, "test", 5);
```

writes `"test"` on the SD card, if for example the memory range `0x00010000`..`0x0001ffff` maps to it.

To dynamically allocate memory on the SD card, like with `malloc` and `free` for regular working memory, a custom allocator would be needed. It would need to handle memory segmentation itself i.e. it needs to map which areas of the memory are free or allocated, and `allocate(len)` needs to find a free segment of length at least `len`. This is normally handled by the operating system.

This can be written in C++ as an *allocator* class, a class which must fulfill the requirements of `Allocator` (concept): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator . For example (incomplete):

```
template<typename T>
class SD_allocator {
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    pointer allocate(std::size_t len) {} // allocate segment of len bytes
    void deallocate(pointer, std::size_t) {}
};
```

If can then be used with STL containers, like:

```
std::vector<int, SD_allocator<int>> vec;
```

uses the memory on the SD card for the items of `vec`. Here they are non-`volatile`, and for meant for use inside the program only, not for persistent storage on the SD card.

The standard allocator in C++ is `std::allocator`, which allocates regular memory like `malloc` and `free`.

Boost seems to provide an allocator which handles segmentation, on a custom defined memory region:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/allocator.html

For persistent storage, such as an SD card, it may be better to define a fixed structure and layout for the data on the SD card, and then read/write to it.

```
struct SDCard_data {
    std::int32_t int1;
    std::int32_t buffer1[500];
    std::int8_t padding_[34];
    int four_bit1 : 4;
    int four_bit2 : 4;
    bool bit1:1;
    bool bit2:1;
    bool bit3:1;
    bool bit4:1;
};

static volatile SDCard_data* sdcard
    = reinterpret_cast<volatile SDCard_data*>(0x0001000);

int write_to_card() {
    // writes to the card
    card->int1 = 32;
    card->bit3 = true;
}
```

## Second case (special instructions)

If reads/writes to the SD card do not correspond to regular memory access instructions on the hardware, data on it cannot be accessed directly using raw `volatile` pointers.

If the goal is to still access it in that way, a class such as `MemDef` would be needed. It may be better to treat the SD card like a file/stream, and instead write/read whole chunks of data to/from it, using functions like `fopen`, `fread`, `fprintf` or similar.

Objects need to be serialized/unserialized for this. Copying a `struct` as raw memory, like

```
struct A;
A a;
write_to_card(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&a), sizeof(A))
```

works as long as the `struct` is a [`PODType`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) and does not contain any pointers/references, i.e. types whose internal representation depends on the memory addresses. It is also dependent on the platform's memory layout (alignment, struct padding), endianness, representation of `float`, `CHAR_BIT`, etc. For cross-platform support (e.g. when the SD-card is read from another device with another microcontroller, some file format would need to be used instead.

It may also be possible (but difficult) to define a custom `Allocator` class, which uses a class like `MemDef` as pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in C++ world in order to abstract memory usually you write a custom allocator. Along the lines

```
template <class T>
class SDAlloc {
 public:
   typedef T        value_type;
   typedef T*       pointer;
   typedef const T* const_pointer;
   typedef T&       reference;
   typedef const T& const_reference;
   typedef std::size_t    size_type;
   typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

   // rebind allocator to type U
   template <class U>
   struct rebind {
       typedef SDAlloc<U> other;
   };

   // return address of values
   pointer address (reference value) const {
       return &value;
   }
   const_pointer address (const_reference value) const {
       return &value;
   }

   SDAlloc(const char* device) {
       // open device by name
       // make helper structures
   }
   ~SDAlloc() {
       // close device
   }

   // return maximum number of elements that can be allocated
   size_type max_size () const throw() {
       return SDsize;
   }

   // allocate but don't initialize num elements of type T
   pointer allocate (size_type num, const void* = 0) {
       // print message and allocate memory on SD
   }

   .......
```